# Finding Element Within Flexbox With Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, flexbox

This is similar to a previously asked question, however all solutions that I have found do not work in my unique scenario with this particular website.

I am attempting to click a single top listing by navigating to the page with selenium, however I am unable to find the listings with selenium because they are nested in a series of flexboxes that contain unique IDs and class names.  Unfortunately, it seems that the only way I can consistently access the listings for all urls would be to use the xpath, but it is unreachable due to the nested flexboxes.

Here is a snippet of the html of the page, with the item I would like to find and click:

[image: stubhub]

Here is my code that is unable to find the element by using the XPATH - I tried using class and CSS selector as well, but was unable to find it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import espected_conditions as EC
-
url = "https://www.stubhub.com/philadelphia-eagles-philadelphia-tickets-1-21-2023/event/151223773/?quantity=2&sections=195411%2C195410%2C195414%2C195413%2C195409%2C195408%2C195412%2C195415%2C195430%2C195427%2C195432%2C195433%2C195431%2C195428%2C195434%2C195429&ticketClasses=594&listingQty=&multi=true"
-
opt = Options()
opt.headless = False
driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=opt)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
-
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button')))
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button').click()
```

This code is opening the browser fine as usual, but throwing a timeout exception once the wait for the element to be clickable times out from not finding the element.

Comment: If the elements you want to get a handle on are in the same frame xpath should work. If there're no unique identifiers for the elements narrow them down using xpath axies[1] and conditional evaluation. [2] - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_axes.asp [2] - https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_operators.asp

Comment: post your python code and the error message, otherwise is hard to help

Comment: Thank you - posted python code and error, hopefully this can help

Comment: What button are you trying to click? I checked the xpath `//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/button` in the browser inspector tool but it found 0 results

Comment: That is strange - I am trying to click on "select" button on the first item in the list on the left

Comment: In my browser the path is slightly different `//*[@id="app"]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/button` however see my answer for a more correct path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case if you want to click the first "Select" button, it is better to use a xpath based on the type of the webelement (`button`) and on the text contained in the button (`Select`)

```
xpath = "//button[text()='Select']"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpath))).click()
```

Alternatively, you can use the css selector in a similar way, but this time we are looking for a `button` with attribute `shape=pill` which is a child of a `div` with attribute `role=button`

```
css = "div[role='button'] button[shape='pill']"
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css))).click()
```

Notice that you can use `.click()` directly after the wait command command